# Docx don't read properly accented word in python

Tags: nltk, tokenize, docx, python-docx, french

I've got a problem when trying to tokenize text using Moses tokenizer. The tokenizer is considering the accented word as 'é' or 'è' as spaces and special characters when tokenizing.

Steps :

1. -- > I read from .docx file
2. -- > Tokenize text with Moses tokenizer

   ```
   from docx import Document
   tokenizer = MosesTokenizer(lang='FR')

   for i in file_docx.paragraphs:
       text = i.text
       tok = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
       print(text) 
       print(tok)
   ```

results :
J'atteste que j'étais présent pour toute la procédure.

```
['J', '\\&apos;', 'atteste', 'que', 'j', '\\&apos;', 'e', '́', 'tais', 'pre', '́', 'sent', 'pour', 'toute', 'la', 'proce', '́', 'dure', '.']
```

Comment: The default encoding that the MosesTokenizer in NLTK expects is `utf-8`. Is there a way to set encoding for `docx.Document`? It looks like it's reading some `latin-1` encoding and then feeding it to the MosesTokenizer that expects `utf8`.